# GRASS GIS 7.2.0 shortcut

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-2.14

I've installed QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.11-1-Setup-x86_64.exe on a windows 7 PC
the installation completes without error, we restarted the PC as requested.
We double clicked the below shortcut:
"GRASS GIS 7.2.0" the shortcut points to "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\bin\grass72.bat" -gui but this file "grass72.bat" does not exist.

Where can I obtain it?

Answer (score 3):

You could try creating a .bat file yourself. Open up *Notepad* (or some other text editor) and paste the following inside:

```
@echo off
rem #########################################################################
rem #
rem # GRASS initialization bat script (OSGeo4W)
rem #
rem #########################################################################

SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14

rem
rem Set environmental variables
rem
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\etc\env.bat

rem
rem Launch GRASS GIS
rem
"%GRASS_PYTHON%" "%GISBASE%\etc\grass72.py" %*

rem
rem Pause on error
rem
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 pause
```

Then save it as "grass72.bat". Once saved, try running it and see if GRASS loads up (it shouldn't matter where you save the file).

Answer (score 1):

Try to rerun the OSGeo4W setup program as administrator: Right click on the setup file and choose "Run As...". That should setup all the shortcuts, batch files etc.